# Insert comma instead of period

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I am writing .bib files for citations. I wanted to add commas but I am getting periods in Bibliography in my Report as shown below:

`Jun Rao. The    Apache  Software    Foundation. Apache --- Architecture and Partitions. https://data-flair.training/blogs/kafka-topic-architecture/. 2018.`

```
@misc{The    Apache  Software    Foundation,
author = "Jun Rao",
title = "{Apache]} --- {A}rchitectue and Partitions ",
year = "2018",
howpublished = {\url{https://data-flair.training/blogs/kafka-topic- 
architecture/}},
}
```

How do I change my bib file to have commas instead of a period in between the entities?

Comment: Your bibliography style decides the format of the bibliography output. It decides whether to use commas or full stops, whether to use italics, quotation marks, ..., it also decides the order of the fields. Your `.bib` file has no say in this. Please tell us what style you use in a short example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: With `biblatex` the answer to your question would be `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`, but it is doubtful that you actually use `biblatex`. With BibTeX the answer strongly depends on the style you use and might be more complicated. So please tell us which bibliography package/system you use (`cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...) and which style you use (the argument to `\bibliographystyle` with BibTeX, the value of the `style` option in `biblatex`).

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography package and which style you use. Without that information we won't be able to help you properly. If there is no edit here in due time I will vote to close this question as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Any news here? If there are no new developments here soon, I will vote to close this question as unclear.